# Which European states require you to physically report in for unemployment?

Tags: europe, unemployment-benefits

In some states in the world, collecting unemployment benefits (assuming you're at all eligible for them) requires physically reporting in to some government office / employment service bureau - on a regular basis (even once a week). In other states, it's the opposite: You can collect your unemployment benefit for months without as much as laying eyes on a relevant government employee - all through the Internet.

My question: Which European states have which reporting requirements for collecting unemployment benefits?

States I already know about:

- **Iceland**: Once a month ([Wikipedia,org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unemployment_benefits))
- **Netherlands**: No physical reporting requirement (by default) if you report through the relevant website.
- **UK**: Once every two weeks ([Gov.UK](https://www.gov.uk/jobseekers-allowance/your-jsa-claim)) <- not brexited just yet...

Note: Of course there are often different cases and different requirements, e.g. if you're disabled you might not be required to report as often or at all; and there may be discretionary reporting requirements in some cases and so on. I'm asking about the default scenario.

Comment: Note that while the Dutch do more and more online and do not require everybody to report on a regular basis just for the sake of showing up, you can be required to report to the UWV.

Comment: @Relaxed: Fair enough; I'll edit to clarify I'm referring to the default scenario.

Comment: Does "periodic interviews at the discretion of the civil servant" count?

Comment: @MartinBonner: In my book it counts as "no periodic reporting requirement by default", but just say _that_ to describe the requirement, in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Germany**

[**§60 SGB II** Mitwirkungs- und Mitteilungspflicht](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/sgb_2/__60.html)

- Requirment to cooperate and to report in

Based on this social law and your specific conditions, you are required to report in to your case manager, when requested, to report about your progress and efforts or anything else required in a letter that may have been sent.

Often the next date is set during the meeting, but a recieved letter may override that date.

*No joy will fall upon you*, if you fail to show up without an accepted excuse.

Comment: A few clarification questions... 1. Is there always an initial meeting with a case manager before you get any money? 2. Are most people required to report in? 3. When you first start getting benefits, what is the typical interval between such meetings?

Comment: You are required to report your unemployment as soon as possible, preferably before the first day. 1) You will then recieve a case manager. 2) Yes, the younger you are more often you have to report. 3) A month used to be typical, but it is now I can't say. The longer it is (6 months) is a sign that they don't think it likly you will find anything. I have heard that for young people (18-20) it can be 2 weeks. The case manager decides.

Comment: But is it two weeks regularly, i.e. "report in every other Thursday at 14:00", or something more flexible?

Comment: It has been a very long time since I have had practical experience in this matter. Then the next appointment was set during the appointment. If something was needed before that, they would send a letter with a new appointment. A regular meeting every Thursday at 14:00 was never demanded, allways an appointment for the next time.